# Create an Auto-sized RichTextBox in Custom WPF control (VB.NET)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox

I have previously used the arguments of a contentsResized event on a Winforms richtextbox to get the new size of my RTB.

I am now developing a WinForms app with a custom WPF RichTextBox.  My whole reason for doing this is to use the out-of-the-box spellchecker.

I need my RichTextBox to expand and collapse vertically as the text is changed.  The elementhost will also have to resize to allow the whole RTB to display on-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to make your `RichTextBox` only be as high as needed, put it in a `StackPanel` like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox Background="Azure" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Otherwise please explain in more detail what your problem is, and if possible post the code that is not working.

Comment: Thank you!   Not only did this solve my problem but it actually got me pointed in a new direction that will RADICALLY improve my program's performance and UI feel.  

Thank you for taking the time to help!